# CSS expand child div to parent with only a background?

Tags: html, css

i've run out of idea's on this one so looking for some help to get this to work. Or maybe confirmation its not possible and a suggestion how i should do it!

I'm re-styling a wordpress site and have added siv's on the left and the right of the main content to position the outside images of a border.

My problem is that i cannot get the div's to expend to the height of the parent!

Here is the layout:

```
<div class="content_botbg">
<div class="content_bg_left"></div>
<div class="content_res"></div>
<div class="content_bg_right"> </div>
<br style="clear:both">
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.content_botbg {
background: none repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
border-bottom: 0 solid #EFEFEF;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 600px;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
width: 988px;
}

.content_bg_left {
    background: url("images/content-container-left.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
}

.content_res {
    background: url("images/transparent_background.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
    width: 940px;
}

.content_bg_right {
    background: url("images/content-container-right.png") repeat-y scroll right center transparent;
    float: left;
    width: 23px;
}
```

Hoping someone can assist as i've been tearing my hair out.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Hi,

content_botbg is the parent container. Unless i'm going crazy?

Comment: Getting elements to expand to 100% height is problematic and in many cases not worth the hassle. Try the following instead. Combine all three images into one and make it the background of content_botbg.

Comment: this may be a posibility. I had split the images to allow it to expand with dynamic content but maybe its not going to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by removing the floats and using some absolute positioning ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXRqT/1/)). It seems like your right side should also be `width: 24px` based off your overall `width`, but I kept it at `23px` (per your code) so it has a `1px` gap in the fiddle example, but that is easily corrected if it is off.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="content_botbg">
<div class="content_bg_left"></div>
<div class="content_res"></div>
<div class="content_bg_right"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.content_botbg {
   border-bottom: 0 solid #EFEFEF;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: left;
   width: 988px;
   position: relative; /* added */
}

.content_bg_left {
    background: url("images/content-container-left.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute; /* replaced float */
    top: 0; /* added */
    bottom: 0; /* added */
    left: 0; /* added */
    width: 24px;
    min-height: 600px; /* moved from content_botbg */
}

.content_res {
    background: url("images/transparent_background.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    /* removed float */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
    width: 940px;
}

.content_bg_right {
    background: url("images/content-container-right.png") repeat-y scroll right center transparent;
    position: absolute; /* replaced float */
    top: 0; /* added */
    bottom: 0; /* added */
    right: 0; /* added */
    width: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Well done that man! it's not perfect but i think one of my background images is slightly out thus the 1px difference but the code is spot on. Obviously, top: 0 and bottom:0 stretch the div without the need for content. Excellent!

Comment: @user1413432--yes, the content of the middle div drives the height of the wrapper div, which (having `position: relative` set) becomes the positioning reference for the two `position: absolute` child elements, allowing the `top` and `bottom` properties to define the height of the elements to the top and bottom of the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding position:relative to the parent div

you then need to specify a width and height for the children.

Lastly, add a special case div (class="content_bg_IE") to expand the other divs for the case of ever-non-compliant-IE

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.content_bg_IE   { height:600px; width:0px; }
.content_botbg {
  background: none repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 0 solid #EFEFEF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 988px;
}

.content_bg_left {
    background: url("images/content-container-left.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 600px;
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
}

.content_res {
    background: url("transparent_background.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    min-height: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0 30px;
    width: 940px;
}

.content_bg_right {
    background: url("images/content-container-left.png") repeat-y scroll right center transparent;
min-height: 600px;
    float: left;
    width: 23px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
hello world!
<div class="content_botbg">
<div class="content_bg_left"><div class="content_bg_IE"></div></div>
<div class="content_res"><div class="content_bg_IE"></div></div>
<div class="content_bg_right"><div class="content_bg_IE"></div></div>
<br style="clear:both">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Afraid this makes no difference.

Comment: the code was updated and should now work well for your scenario. If the height is too high, just set to whatever you want it to be

Comment: i'm afriad this doesnt work either. I believe its because i'm using only a background image with no color property. I cannot specify a colour as it will prevent the opacity of my image working correctly. In testing adding a color does not make a difference anyway.

Comment: I have copied your code directly into a working <html> compliant format. If you copy and past between the <html> tags into a blank file it should be cross-browser compliant doing what you expect. - I just checked IE - and of course, it does something different! I'll work on it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `position:relative` to the parent and then do `height:100%`:

```
.content_botbg {
    position:relative;
    background: none repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid #EFEFEF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 988px;
}
```

And then for the children:

```
.content_bg_left, .content_bg_right, .content_res {
    height:100%;
}
```

The result will be similar to this: http://jsbin.com/arere4

You can find more information about equal height colums at  http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

And additionally, you can use jQuery to achieve the same effect, similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ULUJX/

Comment: i cant disagree with your reasoning, and you example works flawlessly. but it just doesnt work in this case. I beleive its because my divs contain no content....

Comment: If your divs contain no content, they might not scale. You could also manually set `height:zz px;` if the div has nothing in it. 

Do you have a live example of exactly what you're doing, or could you post a jsfiddle of your scenario? There may be other confounding variables here.